# embedding OSX Preview functionality into Objective-C application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, embed, preview

Is it possible to embed OSX Preview functionality into an Objective-C application?

Comment: Objective-C is language. Preview is an Application written for MAC OS X using Cocoa framework. Rephrase your question

Answer (score 1):

Check out the QuickLook framework:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009672

Comment: your answer seems to be related to iOS. It's also useful for me, but can you give me some information about OSX too?

Comment: +1, the Mac has an equivalent framework here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Quicklook_Framework_Reference/_index.html